# Spring Cassandra Operation with If Clause

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, data-persistence

I am trying Cassandra with Spring

I have the Table and Persistence Object, Works Well.

With Cassandra (CQL script) I can make a sentence with: update ...,set ...,  where, .. if ..,

My question is If I can use Spring Cassandra Operation (org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperation) with an Additional "If Sentence".

I want to have a version column and Work with Optimistic Locking (I dont Know yet if this is the best way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data does not support lightweight transactions (`IF` clauses).
You'll have to build `com.datastax.driver.core.Statement`s and execute them with `CqlOperations`.